# Weird compiling error with CodeBlocks - c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

that's my first use to code block but it hasn't gone fine ,, i face a really weird problem
i cant even describe it so i will just tell you what's happened.
the problem is that the ide dont compile my project even if the code were correct
its just open a new tab that called "iostream" and the console window appears but empty
why do that happens ?

look to the code which the ide face a problem while compiling it ,, simplest code ever

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

and this is the compiling results...

[image]

thats all..

will codeblocks stop annoying me ?

Comment: Did you really write it as `unsingnamespace` or did you post fake code? Also, what is the full caption of that black console window?

Comment: @Cyber im not new wich c++ dude ,, im just new with code::blocks ,, and i know that it shouled be typed like that `using namespace std;` and thanks for trying to help ,, the problem has been solved

Comment: It is very nice that "the problem has been solved", but this is not a chat room. And "the problem has been solved" is not something of any value here. If you have a solution - you post it. If there was no problem in the first place - you delete it.

Answer (score 3):

This line is not valid syntax

```
usingnamespace std;
```

Those are two separate keywords

```
using namespace std;
```

And since you are just starting C++, [Lesson 1: Don't do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: How does that explain the behaviour the OP's seen? SO lesson 1: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I'm assuming their lack of the `<string>` include threw a compiler error about missing the `<<` operator definition.

Comment: Do you know what assuming does?

Comment: And what's this about `"Hello World!"` being a `std::string`?? What is "a `std::string` literal"???

Comment: That's called it being late on a Friday and me mixing up my `C++` terminology with my `Python` [terminology](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Comment: You forgot to `code format` the word "terminology". And all the other words. :)

Comment: Wait a minute... why would `"hello"` not be a [string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx) in C++? Is it more correct to refer to it as a `const char` array?

Comment: `"hello"` is a string literal and a `const char[6]`. Nothing to do with `std::string`.